# Can two different entities a program have the same id or must all entities strictly have one id?

Tags: javascript

I'm new in software dev and I'm yet to understand how ids works/are generated from the backend. I'm experimenting with a kanban board app on the front-end in this order:

```
 List1
  -CardA
   -TaskB
  -CardB
   -TaskA
   -TaskB

 List2
  -CardA
   -TaskA
   -TaskB
   -TaskC
  -CardB
   -TaskA
   -TaskB
```

I'm wondering if it's fine to have the same id for two different entities.  I mean, is it Ok for a random Task or Card to have the same id with some other random List or with a Card? Or must all Tasks, Cards or List id be strictly unique no matter what Where they belong to?

Comment: A website / application should only have _unique_ ID's for every page / instance.

Answer (score 0):

[Per HTML 4 spec 7.5.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2):

id = name [CS]
This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.